# How to create a 'headline' theme in beamer which occupies only a portion of the sidebar?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, width, presentations

The `headline` in beamer which spans the width of the top or height of the side in most examples I have seen displays the section/subsection/subsubsection labels. Can I produce a header/headline which is a specified portion/percentage of the slide size or length depending if it was placed along a particular edge?

I have in mind placing the headline as a stunted/shortened rectangle along the top, and beside it to have another 'rectangle' to display the frame title with a logo.

```
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip 0.25pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.8ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%
     \insertsection\insertsubsection\\
    \raggedright\hspace*{5em}\Large\insertframetitle 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
  \vspace{-25pt}
  \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{UCFLOGO}
  \hspace*{0.0cm}
  \vskip0pt
  %{\color{ucfBlack}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}}
}


%footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the theme, but in most standard themes this should be possible.

As you did not provide any code for your headline, I am going to use the headline from the `miniframe` outer theme in the following:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

To adjust the width, you have to do two things

1. Specify the width of the `beamercolorbox`es width `wd={⟨width⟩}`
2. adjusting the width of the navigation element by modifying `\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}`

So for a headline spanning half the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt, wd=.5\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt, wd=.5\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    
\section{1}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{2}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{3}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{4}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{5}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{6}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{7}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{8}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{9}\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\section{10}\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The colour theme is only loaded to make things more visible)

Comment: I am getting an error, `! Undefined control sequence. \beamer@@tmpl@headline ..beamer@theme@subsection \begin {beamercolorbox}[co...`, At the moment I am not importing any theme as I would like to make one from scratch. I cannot figure out where this error I am getting is coming from ...

Comment: @Vass Can you provide a MWE of what you have tried?

Comment: here is a link to the recent state of the .sty file on github, prior to adding your recommended code, https://github.com/mantzaris/PegasusBeamer/blob/master/beamerthemePegasusUCF.sty

Comment: @samcarter: I would like to nominate you for the TUG Membership 2017 'competition' in order to appreciate your enormous support here on TeX.SE (and because your answers are very often underrated :-()

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Please don't worry about the rating of my answers, that is just an intrinsic problem of answering beamer questions. The few occasions I answer different stuff, like `siunitx` there are many upvotes.

Comment: How do I make the `footline` appear at the right of the frame? I am using the `Bergen` theme, and I want the rest of the space after the `sidebar` to be used for this.