# How to right align a footline in beamer which is of reduced length

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am creating a presentation in `beamer` with a few sections and subsections. I am using the `Bergen` theme. I want to add `footline` in my slides. Taking the idea from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352299/162028), I made the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\def\insertauthorindicator{compiled by}
\def\insertinstituteindicator{}
\def\insertdateindicator{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt, wd=.75\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{.75\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt, wd=.75\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=yellow, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue!90!black}


\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=violet}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=violet}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[]{XYZ}
\date[\today]{\today}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \LARGE Section 1
    \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I need to make the following changes in the output:

1. The `footline` should be right aligned, i.e., it should occupy the rest of the right space **after** the `sidebar`. The existing appearance of the `sidebar` must not change.
2. The `footline` should start appearing after the `titlepage`.
3. Only `sectionhead`s should be displayed in the `footline`. For the `subsectionhead`s, I only need a bullet or a circle. I do not want any frame indicator as is present there.
4. The bullets for the subsections should be placed horizontally in the `footline`.
5. The short `sectionhead`s should appear in the `footline`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The `footline` should be right aligned, i.e., it should occupy the rest of the right space **after** the `sidebar`. The existing appearance of the `sidebar` must not change.

you can add `\hfill` before the beamer box

However you won't be happy with the result. By default, the sidebar does not go all the way to the bottom of the page, so there will an ugly white gap.

Instead of the normal sidebar, you could use

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=orange!75!white,bottom=orange!75!white]
```

which will reach all the way to the bottom of the page

> 2. The `footline` should start appearing after the `titlepage`.

either use a `plain` frame for the title page, or temporarily redefine the footline template

> 4. The bullets for the subsections should be placed horizontally in the `footline`.

use the `compress`  option

> 5. The short `sectionhead`s should appear in the `footline`.

The navigation bar will automatically show the short version of teh section name if present

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\def\insertauthorindicator{compiled by}
\def\insertinstituteindicator{}
\def\insertdateindicator{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{.75\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=yellow, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue!90!black}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=orange!75!white,bottom=orange!75!white]

\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=violet}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=violet}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[]{XYZ}
\date[\today]{\today}
\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
}
\section[Sec1]{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \LARGE Section 1
    \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]